# Qt/QML : XmlListModel not able to read the xml file

Tags: xml, qt, qml

I am not able to read a simple xml file using XMLListModel. The below error is shown all times in console.

> Error FODC0002 in tag:trolltech.com,2007:QtXmlPatterns:QIODeviceVariable:src, at line 1, column 38: Unsupported XML version.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>A blog post</title>
        <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2010 10:00:01 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Another blog post</title>
        <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2010 15:35:01 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
</channel>
```

Code:

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480

XmlListModel{
    id: xmlModel
    source: "Test.xml"
    query: "/rss/channel/item"
    XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
    onStatusChanged: {
        console.log("Status Changed...." , status)
        console.log(errorString())
    }
}

MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        console.log(xmlModel.count)
        for(var i = 0 ; i < xmlModel.count ; i++)
        {

            var name = xmlModel.get(i).title
            console.log(name)
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Your .xml is invalid, for example version 1.1 has other rules besides that you need to close </rss>, I have validated it in https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator

Comment: </rss> was a typo. My problem is with version number 1.1. If change that to 1.0 it works all fine. But the file I am getting is having version 1.1, so cannot change xml file manually. Is there any way to load version 1.1 using XmlListModel.?